# Passing HTML email form data to the server UX

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, email, surveys, marketing

I was looking into passing some information from the email to the server for the survey purpose like some companies are doing this already.

[image]

However, I wonder if it is a good idea to take user through all the security message user is presented with once the form is being submitted. For example, if user is using Gmail in Firefox, first user gets one message:

[image]

Then user gets another message:

[image]

Am I right to suggest that the content of these messages can easily put users off submitting survey data, and possibly, trusting your service at all?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the simple answer:

Yes, it will put users off.

- Because it is worrying
- Because it prevents the user from actually doing the tasks, refraining them, and pushing them into cancellation
- Because having two subsequent prompts is tiring
- On top of that, there is no incentive for the user to give a review (except being nice) so don't expect them to go through a complex process for this.

You basically scare users while asking them extra work. Unless the value behind the click is huge, you can expect most users to drop.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to invite a user to share an opinion quickly, which is why it's not a simple, ugly link to a survey.

To (mostly) keep that and remove the security dialogues, you can instead implement those five stars as five links, so that each star opens a web page for the product with the star rating as a URL parameter.

When the user lands on on *that* page submit the *rating* immediately with a confirmation and a thank you. Then give the user the opportunity to provide a written review, if they want.